# How to install php 5.3.8 and mysql 5.5?

Tags: installation, apt, repository, mysql, php

What is the best way to install mysql 5.5 with php 5.3.8 (latest version)? as most of common repositories have only older versions.

Comment: It would probably help here to indicate which version of Ubuntu is used.

Comment: @txwikinger It can be any version, as I have not setup my server yet. Usually, I install Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 5.5 and PHP 5.3.8 are available in **Precise Pangolin**, which will be released as 12.04 this April (probably with PHP 5.3.9, as PHP 5.3.8 has a regression in is_a()).

You can backport those packages to your version with the excellent **backportpackage** tool available in ubuntu-dev-tools. So install that, create a PPA for yourself on launchpad (its so much easier doing builds on launchpad than trying to assemble the build-deps), then do:

```
backportpackage -s precise -r `lsb_release -c -s` -u ppa:youruser/ppaname php5
```

Note that the order is important here, so wait for php5 to finish building before uploading mysql-5.5. Otherwise you'll have to install the libmysqlclient18 from mysql-5.5, which you may not want!

```
backportpackage -s precise -r `lsb_release -c -s` -u ppa:youruser/ppaname mysql-5.5
```

once they're done building you can download the .debs from the PPA or just add them as a source for any servers you want to deploy on with:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:youruser/ppaname
```

Good luck!